# Folders tree with rights

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, treeview, sunos

In OS X and SunOS OS there is no exist the 'bash tree command'.

To plot a tree "graph" of folders i use the following instruction:

```
find . -type d -print | sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'
```

Or this to show files too.

```
find . -print | sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'
```

But i need another version which contains also the folders rights. Im pretty lost to add on the right side the folder rights. Anyone have any idea ??

**Update:**
There are any option to plot the files inside the folders and their rights too. I'm trying with this command `find . -print | sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'` and doing combination with the solution provided by #fedorqui but the result aren't so good.

That's the result obtained with the above command, without rights.

```
| | |____src
| | | |____cft2exit.c
| | | |____cft2exit_AIX
| | | |____cft2exit_SUN
| | | |____gestidt.c
| | | |____gestidt.h
| | | |____gestidt.o
| | | |____gestidt_AIX
| | | |____gestidt_SUN
| | | |____gestidt_SunOS
| | | |____makefile
| | | |____sem.a
| | | |____ut_sem.c
| | | |____ut_sem.h
| | | |____ut_sem.o
| |____data
| | |____purge.dat
| |____lost+found
```

Comment: This is a very tricky and nice way, congrats. Do you mean having something like `___dir1  drwxrwxr-x`?

Comment: Yeah, exactly what you write.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can execute `ls -ld` for each result of `find`. It will give you the permissions, other things, and then the file name. If you then pipe to awk, with `awk '{print $NF, $1}'` you can print both blocks of information. Finally, you pipe to your `sed` command. All together:

```
find . -type d -exec ls -ld {} \; | awk '{print $NF, $1}' | sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'
```

#### Test

```
$ find . -type d -exec ls -ld {} \; | awk '{print $NF, $1}' | sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'
. drwxrwxr-x
|____python drwxrwxr-x
| |____jinja2 drwxrwxr-x
| | |____bk drwxrwxr-x
| | |____infiles drwxrwxr-x
.......
```

In small steps:

```
$ find . -type d -exec ls -ld {} \;
drwxrwxr-x 7 me me 4096 Aug 15 15:35 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 me me 4096 Aug 13 14:31 ./python
drwxrwxr-x 4 me me 4096 Apr 26 15:14 ./python/jinja2
drwxrwxr-x 2 me me 4096 Apr 19 14:26 ./python/jinja2/bk
drwxrwxr-x 2 me me 4096 Apr 19 12:54 ./python/jinja2/infiles
```

and then

```
$ find . -type d -exec ls -ld {} \; | awk '{print $NF, $1}' 
. drwxrwxr-x
./python drwxrwxr-x
./python/jinja2 drwxrwxr-x
./python/jinja2/bk drwxrwxr-x
./python/jinja2/infiles drwxrwxr-x
```

Comment: doesn't find have a '-ls' option ??

Comment: @Dru not that I know of.

Comment: Is there any option to show folders and also the files into their folder, all with their rights. I'm trying with your solution combining with this other command find . -print | sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'  , but the result is not so good.

Comment: @JorgeVegaSánchez Mmmm I am not sure I understand what you mean. Can you update your question with a sample input/output?

Comment: @JorgeVegaSánchez now I see. But note that my solution was providing the rights of the files next to each line. By using `find . -type d -exec ls -ld {} \;` they appear.

Comment: Yes, I try  using this part of your solution changing the ls -ld by ls -l but the output was weird. I can see the rights but I can see the folder of a group of files.

Comment: @JorgeVegaSánchez it is important to use `ls -ld` because the `-d` gives info about the directory. Otherwise with `ls -l` you are printing the content of every particular directory.

Comment: That's the main problem, combine both or something like this to show folders and files into with the rights on the right side.

Answer (score 2):

On OS X you can install `tree`, using [homebrew](http://brew.sh):

```
brew install tree
```

or, using [macports](http://www.macports.org):

```
sudo port install tree
```

and then, to view directories with permissions:

```
$ tree -p -d
```

Sample output:

```
.
├── [drwxr-xr-x]  folder1
│   └── [drwxr-xr-x]  folder2
│       └── [drwxr-xr-x]  folder3
│           └── [drwxr-xr-x]  folder4
└── [drwxr-xr-x]  folder5
    ├── [drwxr-xr-x]  folder6
    └── [drwxr-xr-x]  folder7
```