# Shell script to write folder tree structure to file

Tags: bash, shell

I need a shell script that writes the tree structure (including all data in the folders) from a specific folder to a text/dat file.

So far I got this:

```
find . -type f|sed 's_\.\/__' > PATH/Input.dat
```

I dont want a "/" as the first char of the path.

This script works fine, but it returns ALL folder structures. I need something that returns only structures from a specific folder, like "Sales".

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18255609/1983854

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need something that returns only structures from a specific folder,
>   like "Sales".

Specify the desired folder name.  Say:

```
find Sales -type f | sed 's_\.\/__'
     ^^^^^
```

Saying `find . ...` would search in `.` (i.e. *the current directory* and subdirectories).

If you need to search more *folders*, say `Purchase`, specify those too:

```
find Sales Purchase -type f | sed 's_\.\/__'
```

Comment: Probably that `sed` then becomes obsolete.

Comment: @Alfe Yes, if you are specifying a path the result wouldn't have a leading `./`.  I'd say it becomes _redundant_ rather than _obsolete_ :)

Comment: If I specify a path ≠ `.`, that is ;-)

Comment: @Alfe `.` is default (even if you don't specify it).

Comment: Actually, paths like `Sales/some/weird/path./with./strange./names` would get ugly garbled by that `sed`, so it does not really get _redundant_ but _wrong_, so _obsolete_ fits better.

Comment: Is it somehow possible to order the output in a some kind of order?

Comment: @user2428207 Could you elaborate _some kind of order_?

Comment: for example order by subfolder and then filename. Lets say I have three folders in my "find Sales" folder. A, B and C. Each folder has files 1, 2 and 3. Now I would like to have Folder A;1,2,3 Folder B;1,2,3 and so on.