# Tree functionality using sed and find command

Tags: unix, sed, tree, find

```
find . -type d -print | sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'
```

Came across this commandline on unix.com which acts as tree command in unix.
I want to someone to explain what that sed command is exactly doing.
i'm unable to understand the syntax

Right now i know the basic sed command syntax. I'm still getting a hang of the unix environment .

PS: Command works perfectly and The discussion was closed in that forum.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18255609/1983854

Comment: @ fedorqui i understand what the final output is but i want to know what exactly is sed command doing. i'm unable understand the syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `find` command is only looking for directories and printing them.

`sed` command is as follows:

```
sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^
         |               |
         |               replace ____| with  |
         replace everything up to the last / with ____
```

Let's see the command in action step by step:

Find all the directories and print its name:

```
$ find . -type d -print 
.
./python
./python/mytest
./python/mytest2
./python/mytest2/bk
./python/mytest2/infiles
./bash
./bash/backup
./awk
./sed
```

Replace everything up to the last `/` with `____`:

- `sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g'` is read like this:

  - `[^/]*` --> get all characters as possible (`*`) that are different than `/`. Note that `^` stands for negation here.
  - `/` --> match a `/`.
  - given that block, replace it with the string `|____`.

See an example:

```
$ echo "hello/how/are/you" | sed 's;[^/]*/;;g'
you

$ echo "hello/how/are/you" | sed 's;[^/]*/;|____;g'
|____|____|____you
```

In this case:

```
$ find . -type d -print | sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g'
.
|____python
|____|____mytest
|____|____mytes2
|____|____|____bk
|____|____|____infiles
|____bash
|____|____backup
|____awk
|____sed
```

Replace `____|` with `|`:

```
$ find . -type d -print | sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'
.
|____python
| |____mytest
| |____mytest2
| | |____bk
| | |____infiles
|____bash
| |____backup
|____awk
|____sed
```

We normally see `sed` expressions like:

```
sed 's/hello/bye/g'
```

but you can use different delimiters if you suspect `/` can be problematic. So in this case the delimiter is `;`:

```
sed 's;hello;bye;g'
```

Finally, note that:

```
sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^
         1st command     2nd command
```

means that two commands are to be executed one after the other, so it is equivalent to:

```
sed 's;[^/]*/;|____;g' | sed 's;____|; |;g'
```